# Unexpected Output While std::cout float32 data twice, which previously swapped by _mm_shuffle_pi16

Tags: c++, assembly, sse, ieee-754, mmx

English is not my first language, please forgive my grammar mistake

my machine env is

```
AMD 5900x, win10 latest, VS2022 MSVC lateset
```

following code have passed compile(debug-X86, release-x86 MSVC)on my machine and my  colleague's machine(which is pretty similar to mine), but the output isn't expected

```cpp
#include <intrin.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    union
    {
        float f[2];
        __m64 m;
    } a = {{10.f, 200.f}};

    a.m = _mm_shuffle_pi16(a.m, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 0, 3, 2));
    std::cout << a.f[0] << " " << a.f[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << a.f[0] << " " << a.f[1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

```bash
expected output:
200 10
200 10


ACTUAL output:
-nan(ind) 10
200 10
// note: no math operation undertake between two std::cout
```

I have checked the under binary data, they both legal in IEEE 754 standard：

[image]

[image]

the disassembly is pretty normal:

[image]

which really makes me think is there any up-stream BUG? Or any compile env issue? any similar situation have you met? any advice or further info needed? thanks in advance.

UPDATE1:
same code on

```bash
Linux kali 6.3.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.3.7-1kali1 (2023-06-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux

gcc (Debian 13.1.0-6) 13.1.0
g++ (Debian 13.1.0-6) 13.1.0
Debian clang version 14.0.6
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

```
compile command:

g++ a.cpp

clang++ -o aaa a.cpp
```

output(for both compile method):

```
200 10
200 10
```

[image]

Comment: *any up-stream BUG? Or any compile env issue?* No. Your code exhibits UB. The union active member is `float f[2]`. Accessing `a.m` results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @273K: That means the code is not *portable*, but doesn't explain the behaviour on MSVC at all.  MSVC *does* define the behaviour of union type-punning in C++ the same as in C99, and in fact uses unions this was as part of defining `__m128` and `__m128i`.  (Some other mainstream C++ compilers like GCC and Clang also define the behaviour.)  So that part is well-defined on the implementations the OP tried. Apparently there were some compilers that supported Intel intrinsics without defining the behaviour of union type-punning in C++, like Sun CC IIRC, so we'd expect breakage there.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't know what *exactly* happened between assigning to `a.m` and stuff being printed, there is a bug in the code itself: `_mm_shuffle_pi16` is an MMX intrinsic, and you did not call `_mm_empty` (or `_m_empty`), so the FPU-state is still in MMX-mode. That would disrupt x87-style FPU instructions later. You compiled for x86 (so 32-bit), so it is likely that x87 instructions were used at some point. 64-bit code mostly doesn't use x87 instructions, in that case it may seem like nothing bad happened, which could explain why the code appeared to work on 64bit kali linux.

MMX is retrocomputing at this point. You could add `_mm_empty` to fix this code, but you may as well use SSE instead. Ditch the union (you can use the "cast" family of intrinsics to do safe reinterpretation if needed, but you don't need it here since SSE has a floating point shuffle), and do something like this:

```
__m128 a = _mm_setr_ps(10.0f, 200.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
a = _mm_shuffle_ps(a, a, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 2, 0, 1));
float test[4];
_mm_storeu_ps(test, a);
std::cout << test[0] << " " << test[1] << std::endl;
```

There have historically been [some compiler bugs with `_mm_empty`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47759), but that's not what you're seeing in your program, there is no `_mm_empty` in it to begin with.

Comment: To do 64-bit load/store to `__m128` if you do only have pairs of floats, use `movsd`:  `__m128d _mm_load_sd (double const* mem_addr)` and `_mm_store_sd` are supposed to be strict-aliasing and alignment safe, so you can use them on `float` data even though you have to cast to `double*`.  Or for the store you can use SSE1 `movlps`, with the unfortunately named and typed `void _mm_storel_pi (__m64* mem_addr, __m128 a)` which uses `__m64*` instead of `float*`.  Despite the `_pi` naming and `__m64*` operand, it stores from an XMM register and is unrelated to MMX, no `_mm_empty` needed.